# High res preview of vector art in Adobe Bridge

Tags: adobe-bridge

I've downloaded some high definition vector art from Shutterstock recently but the artboard dimensions used by some artists are tiny; for example, 30 x 10px!

Adobe Bridge sees those tiny dimensions and renders a preview based on these. These previews are then illegible.

Anybody know a trick to get "upscaled" previews for vectors? (I'd rather not have  to resize the artwork in Illustrator...)

Thanks in advance

Gabe

Comment: Vectors don't have a resolution. What you are looking at would seem to be thumbnails. What file format are the files you are trying to view? Have you tried opening the files? Do they contain vectors or raster images?

Comment: @BillyKerr - OP is clear on this I think - their point is that Bridge's thumbnailing system is being foozled by the original artist having chosen a very small artboard for their work in Illustrator, and as Bridge creates its thumbnails (or imports the OS thumbnails) the small declared-size artboard results in a tiny dimensions thumbnail - OP's asking if there is some tool or technique to force Bridge to reset thumbnail size **other** than entering each Illustrator file and resetting artboard size there.

Comment: @GerardFalla - I see what you mean.  Probably no way to change that behaviour in Bridge, but it might be possible to write a script to resize artoards and their contents in Illustrator. Way beyond my abilities unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I think you end up copy/pasting the vector art contents into new Illustrator files with appropriately sized artboards.

Comment: Hey @GerardFalla - thanks for taking the time with this. Unfortunately, despite really not wanting to be resizing artwork, I think you may be right that it's the only available workaround ATM. 

(There's the added issue that some of these illustrations are making very heavy use of effects. In my experience, this adds complication when resizing. Hopefully, Illustrator's scale strokes and effects option is working more reliably than when I last got burnt doing this a few years ago!)

In the meantime - time for a feature request for Adobe...